# How do I get the total number of distinct values in a column in a CSV?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV file named `test.csv`. It looks like this:

```
1,Color
1,Width
2,Color
2,Height
```

I want to find out how many distinct values are in the first column. The shell script should return `2` in this case.

I tried running `sort -u -t, -k2,2 test.csv`, which I saw on another question, but it printed out far more info than I need.

How do I write a shell script that prints the number of distinct values in the first column of `test.csv`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1]++{c++} END{print c}' file

2
```

This awk command uses key `$1`, and stores them in an array seen. Value of which is incremented to 1 when a key is populated first time. Every time we get a unique key we increment count `c` and print it in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
cut -d, -f1 file | sort -u | wc -l
```

Use `cut` to extract the first column, then `sort` to get the unique values, then `wc` to count them.

Answer (score 2):

```
#List the first column of the CSV, then sort and filter uniq then take count. 

awk -F, '{print $1}' test.csv  |sort -u  |wc -l
```

To ignore header:

```
   awk -F, 'NR>1{print $1}' test.csv  |sort -u  |wc -l
```

Comment: How to do this to ignore header row?